# How do I make my geofences still get triggered if the app is not in the background at the event?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, geofencing

I have created an app which monitors the movement across geofences and sends a notification on these events but these notifications aren't sent if the app is not running in the background/foreground.

Obviously it is extremely impractical if the app must always be open for these geofences to be triggered so I was wondering if there was any way for this to be worked around.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
I have searched for an answer but haven't found anything related to iOS 10/Swift3

Comment: If the app has been terminated by swiping up in the app switcher then it won't run again until the user launches it